# Calling stty from a systemd service

Tags: systemd, tty

I have an `expect` script that I want to run at startup. Among other things it configures a few serial ports. When I run it via systemd I get:

`couldn't read file "/dev/tty": no such device or address
while executing
exec /bin/stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ... </dev/tty`

I figure this is because `systemd` runs services as processes without a controlling terminal, but is there a way around the problem? The script that gets called has no reference to `/dev/tty`:

`stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ...`

Comment: You would have helped answerers significantly had you mentioned that this is an `expect` script, not a shell script, and indeed not cut that out of the error message.

Comment: There's nothing in the error message about an `expect`. Parts of the script indeed use `expect`, though not the `stty` part explicitly. But yes, it's true the script is called with `expect`. I didn't realize it was significant.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to tell `stty` which tty to configure, either use `-F /dev/your_tty`, or redirect stdin as in `< /dev/your_tty`.

Using both makes no sense. Just get rid of the `< /dev/tty` at the end.

**Edit**

With your edit: Now the question is why an `stty` call is translated into one with `< /dev/tty` in the first place.

Comment: Right. Where do the `exec` and `/dev/tty` come from?

Comment: First thing I'd do is to looking at the complete service description file for what you are doing. Second thing I'd do is look closely at the script.

Comment: Third option is to check if `stty` without a path somehow is a script, alias etc. which expands to `/bin/stty ... < /dev/tty`.

Comment: `[Unit]
Description=script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=script.sh
Restart=no
After=some services

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: `$ strace stty` gives: `execve("/bin/stty", ["stty"], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0` -- doesn't look like option 3

Comment: @user907323 what does `file /bin/stty` say?

Comment: The whole thing? It's an executable. "/bin/stty: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=c570584ce327612b433e4b2de8538a84385bedca, stripped"

Comment: Hmmm and is your `script.sh` maybe defining a function that overrides `stty`?

Comment: Doesn't look like it does, no.